# How should I read the syntax descriptions in the JLS?

Tags: java, jls

From the [Java Language Specification (third edition), section 3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.10.5):

> ```
> StringLiteral:
>         " StringCharactersopt "
>
> StringCharacters:
>         StringCharacter
>         StringCharacters StringCharacter
>
> StringCharacter:
>         InputCharacter but not " or \
>         EscapeSequence
> ```

Can someone please help me understand this syntax pattern?
What could `xx: " xxx`<sub>`opt`</sub>`"` mean?

Comment: You ought to check Chapter 2 of the JLS for the grammar notation used. The symbol `opt` is defined in the same chapter as: `The subscripted suffix "opt", which may appear after a terminal or nonterminal, indicates an optional symbol.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means a `StringLiteral` is a double-quote, an optional `StringCharacters` token, and a double quote.  "opt" means optional.

`StringCharacters` is defined as one or more `StringCharacter` tokens.

`StringCharacter` is either an `InputCharacter` (defined elsewhere) except for a double-quote or a backslach; or an `EscapeSequence` (also defined elsewhere)